# Will the IIS Application Warm Up Module work on IIS 7.0?

Tags: iis-7, iis-7.5

Will the [IIS Application Warm Up Module](http://www.iis.net/download/applicationwarmup) work on IIS 7.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it will not. The Application Warm up module uses a set of new notification events (and interfaces) added in IIS 7.5 so there is no way to make that work, it requires changes in WAS and other pieces, so it will not work unless using IIS 7.5.